# The placement of tumblr permalink notes in the code

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

So, basically what I want is to have my permalink notes to appear with my tumblr posts on every permalink page. I've heard somewhere that in order to make them appear, you have to add them to each post individually, instead of just placing them once before {/block:Posts}:

e.g

```
{block:Photo}

{block:PostNotes}
{PostNotes-64}
{/block:PostNotes} 

{/block:Photo}


{block:Quote}

{block:PostNotes}
{PostNotes-64}
{/block:PostNotes} 

{/block:Quote}
```

I'm just wondering if you really do have to put it inside every single post for it to work, instead of just one spot in the code?

If not, then where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `{PostNotes}` is inside the `{block:Posts}` loop, they will render.

**Example**

```
{block:Posts}

{block:Photo}
<img src="{PhotoURL-500} />
{/block:Photo}

{block:PostNotes}
{PostNotes-64}
{/block:PostNotes} 

{/block:Posts}
```